# wpf making a progress bar accesible from a method

Tags: c#, wpf

I rode a code which puts the quantity of the different words in a txt file in a datagrid. Now I am tryin to add a progress bar, but i cant access it from the method in which i organize the words. Unfortunately i was told that i have to split, count, etc the words in a method (I cant do it in start()). Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
    
    private void start(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = txtbox_path.Text;
        string unordered = readFile(path);
        var ordered = count(unordered);
        progressbar_1.Maximum = ordered.Count;
        foreach(var obj in ordered)
        {
            datagrid_table.Items.Add(obj);
            progressbar_1.Value += 1;
        }
    }
    private string readFile(string filePath)
    {
        string content = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            content = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            lbl_warning.Content=e.Message;
        }
        return content;
    }
    public static IDictionary count(string input)
    {
        var split = input.Split();
        var grouped = split.GroupBy(x => x);
        var ordered = grouped.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
        
        var counted = from s in ordered
                      select new
                      {
                          word = s.Key,
                          number = split.Where(x => x.Equals(s.Key)).Count()
                      };
        
        var asList = counted.ToList();
        
        var orderedByNumber = asList.OrderByDescending(x => x.number);
       

        var whitespacesRemoved = orderedByNumber.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.word));
       
        var asDict = whitespacesRemoved.ToDictionary(p => p.word, p => p.number);
       
        return asDict;
    }

    private void stop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part of your code takes such a long time that a progress bar would be useful? If is the reading of the file, or the evaluation, or the display in the UI?

Comment: I am trying to use it in count()

Comment: Just don't make `count()` static, and you have access to your ProgressBar object.

Comment: Sie sind der Beste Herr Gütter :*